# How to support marathi text in Android?

Tags: android, fonts

Is there any way to support marathi font in android? I tried by adding font in assest forlder but not working. Is there any other way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used a font for the encoding ISCII 57002 (Devanagari), try a Unicode font, as Android uses UTF-8, Unicode. Maybe [this](http://chetangole.com/blog/2011/08/enabling-installing-hindi-marathi-unicode-fonts-on-android-mobile/). *Not much experience in this area of Android.*